# Html element have double box-shadow effect?

Tags: css, hover, box-shadow

I have this styling :

```css
.col-md-6.active:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(33,33,33,.2); 
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 active" style="border: 0.5px solid; box-shadow: 5px  5px #99ccff;  border-radius: 5px; width: 500px; height:700px;margin-right:1px;float:left"></div>
```

But this hover effect is not having any effect , it wont show . How can i solve that ? Thanks in regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not seeing the Hover effect due to [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) your inline box shadows have priority, over the css `:hover` rules...

to fix it use !important or remove those role from your inline style

```css
.col-md-6.active:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(33,33,33,.2) !important; 
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 active" style="border: 0.5px solid; box-shadow: 5px  5px #99ccff;  border-radius: 5px; width: 500px; height:700px;margin-right:1px;float:left">
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline css has a higher priority than the css added by your class. You can overwrite the css with `!important`.

```css
.col-md-6.active:hover {
   box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(33,33,33,.2) !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 active" style="border: 0.5px solid; box-shadow: 5px 5px #99ccff; border-radius: 5px; width: 500px; height:700px; margin-right:1px; float:left">
</div
```

Note, another and cleaner fix would be to move your inline css to a class.

Answer (score 1):

Do your styling in css, not inline.

```css
.col-md-6.active{
  border: 0.5px solid;
  box-shadow: 5px  5px #99ccff;
  border-radius: 5px; 
  width: 500px; 
  height:700px;
  margin-right:1px;
  float:left
}
.col-md-6.active:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(33,33,33,.2); 
  }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 active"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put your inline styles in the css file like this.

```css
.col-md-6.active {
  border: 0.5px solid  ;
  box-shadow: 5px  5px #99ccff;  
  border-radius: 5px; 
  width: 500px; 
  height:700px;
  margin-right:1px;
  float:left
}
.col-md-6.active:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 11px rgba(33,33,33,.2); 
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6 active"></div>
```